# How to refer previous task and stop the build in azure devops if there is no new data to publish an artifact

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, scripting, conditional-statements, azure-pipelines

Getsolution.exe will give New data available or no new data available, if new data available then next jobs should be executed else nothing should be executed. How should i do it? (i am working on classic editor)

example: i have set of tasks, consider 4 tasks:

task-1: builds the solution

task-2: runs the Getstatus.exe which get the status of data available or no data available

task-3: i should be able to use the above task and make a condition/use some api query and to proceed to publish an artifact if data is available if not cleanly break out of the task and stop the build. it Shouldn't proceed to publish artifact or move to the next available task

task-4:publish artifact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First what you need is to set a variable in your task where you run `Getstatus.exe`:

[image]

and then set condition in next tasks:

[image]

If you set `doThing` to different valu than `Yes` you will get this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it runs all step in example above but if you set `doThing` sth different than `yes` than last step will be skipped.

Comment: I was able to cancel my task and skip the next tasks but the release kicked off. Is there a way to stop the triggering of release if build is canceled

Answer (score 0):

> How to refer previous task and stop the build in azure devops if there is no new data to publish an artifact

Since we need to execute different task based on the different results of `Getstatus.exe` running, we need set the condition based on the result of `Getstatus.exe` running.

To resolve this, just like the Krzysztof Madej said, we could set variable(s)  based on the return value of `Getstatus.exe` in the inline powershell task:

```
$dataAvailable= $(The value of the `Getstatus.exe`）

if ($dataAvailable -eq "True")
{
  Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=Status]Yes")
}
elseif ($dataAvailable -eq "False")
{
  Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=Status]No")
}
```

[image]

Then set the different condition for next task:

[image]

You could check the document [Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for some more details.

Comment: i made a similar script and was able to cancel my build but the release still kicked off, need to stop the release trigger as well once build is cancelled.
Its the same scenario after i followed @Krzysztof Madej

Comment: @Devops-bee, You may enable the CD (Continuous deployment trigger) for the release pipeline, am i right? In this case, when you build pipeline completion, it will trigger the release pipeline. If you want to stop the release trigger as well once build is cancelled, you could disable the CD, then add the task Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline&targetId=c519b80d-5d71-46b3-a8e0-3edf8c026ea2 with condition above. It will not trigger the release pipeline if the task/build pipeline not executed.

Comment: Lie-MSFT. It helped. Thanks